# Know-how en français

Tags: anglicismes

J'étais récemment en Allemagne et j'ai observé l'emploi des mots et expressions anglaises dans la publicité. Un tel exemple est *know-how*.

Peut-on employer know-how en français ?

Comment: Ce n'est pas assez précis : la question de pouvoir peut être prise sous plusieurs angles ; il n'y a aucun empêchement à l'emploi de n'importe quel terme étranger lorsque on veut donner au lecteur le savoir d'un mot qui n'a pas d'équivalent dans sa langue, par exemple ; on peut aussi vouloir forcer un néologisme et employer n'importe quel mot et dans beaucoup de cas cela ne résultera pas en des conséquences bien importantes ; la question devrait être différente ou plus précise quant à la possibilité envisagée.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oui! Évidemment qu'on peut! Le français ne s'interdit : RIEN!

J'ai toujours néanmoins, pour ma part préféré le très français *savoir-faire* qui dit ni plus ni moins que la même chose.

Je reconnais que ses potes (*know-why*, *know-what*) n'ont pas vraiment d'équivalents immédiats (peut-être est-ce un signe qu'ils ne servent pas à grand-chose...) Alors, oui!, si, dans un même papier, j'utilise ces deux derniers alors, je garderai le premier en anglais dans le texte. (c.a.d en italiques)

Cela peut se comprendre pour l'Allemand... je ne sais pas si *Handlungswissen* ferait très... vendeur! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

En France, la loi Toubon [impose](https://www.economie.gouv.fr/dgccrf/Publications/Vie-pratique/Fiches-pratiques/emploi-langue-francaise) qu'une publicité soit rédigée en français.

On peut bien sûr y déroger dans certains cas (*What else...*), mais la traduction des phrases ou mots étrangers devra alors être présente et clairement lisible.